# Json responsed data not display

Tags: jquery, json

I have a json response string as follows:

```
[
  {
    "0":
        {
          "total":"2.00"
        },
    "PaymentCollection":
        {
          "emp_id":"E0004"
        }
  }
]
```

and my jQuery function is

```
$.each(resp,function(indx,obj){
    alert(obj.0.total);
});
```

Unfortunately the alert is not working.. please help

Comment: try `alert(obj['0'].total);`

Answer (score 1):

`.0` is not valid in javascript (an identifier can't start with a digit). You can use the "array notation" : `alert(obj["0"].total);`

Comment: `obj.["0"].total` will give always error. You have added extra `.`. Upvoter please check before upvote its correct or not.

Comment: Oops. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can access like this:

```
obj['0'].total
```

or

```
obj['0']['total']
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/a8em0k0L/)